# Validate uniqueness depending of other field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table Users with a boolean field "active".
I need to put a uniqueness validation of the user name but only among the active users.

I've try a

```
 validates :name, :uniqueness => true, :if => "active == true"
```

But it's still throw a error because inactive user have the same name.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`validates :name, :uniqueness => { :scope => :active }, :if => :active`

ought to do it

more info:

what this does is it checks for uniqueness of name but only among other users with the same value for the `active` column. That almost gets you what you want, but since you don't care whether two inactive users have the same name, we only run the validation if the user's `active` method returns a "truthy" value (i.e., `true`, since this is just an accessor for a boolean attribute). The end result is we validate only active users for uniqueness of name but only among other active users.

Comment: please accept the answer if it solves your problem and is clear and comprehensive enough!